# Javascript html displaying

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I would like to re-display my page the same way as before.(The same layout). i basically got a h1 title and the moment i click on that title it will add strings to my p1. When i click on p1 it will then chose a random string to remove. It will then have to redisplay the same page but with only one line of string removed. The problem i have is that it removes my h1 title and the canvas i created when i click on p1.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #canvas{
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            background: green;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var maFonction=function(elem,event,couleur)
    {
        elem.style.color=couleur;
    }

    var insertText=function( text)
    {
        var elem=text;
        elem.innerHTML+=text;
    }

    var newtable=new Array();
    var tablenew= new Array();

    newtable[0]="Ce petit chien est tres drole.";
    newtable[1]="Il est blanc, avec une oreille blanche et une oreille noire.";
    newtable[2]="Il a aussi le bout de la queue noir.";
    newtable[3]="Il a une oreille en l'air et une oreille en bas";
    newtable[4]="Oui, il est tres drole.";
    newtable[5]="Ce petit chien est aussi tres gai.";
    newtable[6]="Il joue toute la journee.";
    newtable[7]="C'est un vrai petit diable de toutou.";
    newtable[8]="Paf joue à la balle avec Theo et avec Emilie. ";
    newtable[9]="Quand la balle tombe, Paf l'attrape.";
    newtable[10]="Il se sauve avec la balle ou bien il la pousse avec sa patte et il court.";
    newtable[11]="Quand Emilie saute à la corde, Paf saisit la corde, et tire; il se sauve ou il l'emporte.";
    newtable[12]="Quand Theo joue aux billes, Paf joue avec lui.";
    newtable[13]="Avec sa patte, il gratte le trou, il fait sauter les billes, il les fait rouler de tous cotes.";
    newtable[14]="Theo se fache un peu. ";
    newtable[15]=" Mais Paf s'amuse si bien et il est si drole, que Theo finit par rire de tout son coeur.";
    newtable[16]="HISTOIRE: http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-55950.php";

    var line = 0;
    var clickSurSection2 = function(newtable,element)
    {
        document.getElementById("story").innerHTML += "<br>"+ newtable[line];
        tablenew.push(newtable[line]);
        line++;
    }

    var pushTable=function(tablenew)
    {
        var theindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*tablenew.length);
        tablenew.splice(theindex);

        for(var i=0;i<tablenew.length;i++)
        {
            document.write(tablenew[i]+" </br>");
        }
    }
    </script>

    <h1 onmouseover="maFonction(this,event,'red');"
        onmouseout="maFonction(this,event,'blue');"
        onclick="clickSurSection2(newtable,this);">
            Cliquez moi pour en savoir plus
    </h1>

    <div id="story">
        <p1 onclick="pushTable(tablenew);">Il y a a la maison un petit chien.</p1>
    </div>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Did you really think making the title *exactly* the same as the tags was a good idea? What is "the same as before"?

Comment: Put a more descriptive title. Also, what do you mean with "the same as before"? What is before?

Comment: when i execute the page it basically has a h1 title with a p1 string and a green canvas under the p1 text. The problem is that when i try to remove one string from p1 and redisplaying p1 it removes my h1 and canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for, if I understand the question correctly:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="heading" onmouseover="maFonction('red');"
        onmouseout="maFonction('blue');"
        onclick="clickSurSection2(newtable,this);">
            Cliquez moi pour en savoir plus
    </h1>

    <div id="story">
        <p class="paragraph" onclick="pushTable();">Il y a a la maison un petit chien.</p>
    </div>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS stays the same

JS:

```
var heading = document.getElementById('heading');
var story = document.getElementById("story");
var paragraph = document.getElementsByClassName('paragraph');
var newtable=[];
newtable[0]="Ce petit chien est tres drole.";
newtable[1]="Il est blanc, avec une oreille blanche et une oreille noire.";
newtable[2]="Il a aussi le bout de la queue noir.";
newtable[3]="Il a une oreille en l'air et une oreille en bas";
newtable[4]="Oui, il est tres drole.";
newtable[5]="Ce petit chien est aussi tres gai.";
newtable[6]="Il joue toute la journee.";
newtable[7]="C'est un vrai petit diable de toutou.";
newtable[8]="Paf joue à la balle avec Theo et avec Emilie. ";
newtable[9]="Quand la balle tombe, Paf l'attrape.";
newtable[10]="Il se sauve avec la balle ou bien il la pousse avec sa patte et il court.";
newtable[11]="Quand Emilie saute à la corde, Paf saisit la corde, et tire; il se sauve ou il l'emporte.";
newtable[12]="Quand Theo joue aux billes, Paf joue avec lui.";
newtable[13]="Avec sa patte, il gratte le trou, il fait sauter les billes, il les fait rouler de tous cotes.";
newtable[14]="Theo se fache un peu. ";
newtable[15]=" Mais Paf s'amuse si bien et il est si drole, que Theo finit par rire de tout son coeur.";
newtable[16]="HISTOIRE: http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-55950.php";
var tablenew= [];
tablenew[0] = paragraph[0].innerText;
var line = 0;

function maFonction(couleur){
  heading.style.color=couleur;
}

function insertText(text){
  var elem=text;
  elem.innerHTML+=text;
}

function clickSurSection2(newtable,element){
  var newParagraph = '<p class="paragraph" onclick="pushTable();">'+newtable[line]+'</p>';
  story.innerHTML += newParagraph;
  tablenew.push(newtable[line]);
  line++;
}

function pushTable(){
  var theindex=Math.floor(Math.random()*tablenew.length);
  tablenew.splice(theindex, 1);
  var newParagraph;
  story.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i=0;i<tablenew.length;i++){
    newParagraph = '<p class="paragraph" onclick="pushTable();">'+tablenew[i]+'</p>';
    story.innerHTML += newParagraph;
  }
}
```

And here is a link to the jsBin example: http://jsbin.com/gicig/3/edit